# Create react modal in specific div instead of rendering body

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, reactstrap

I'm trying to create modal popup into specific div, but it created into body at bottom

```
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
            Close </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
            Save Changes</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Please add minimum barebone of code it's hard to tell without any code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem in your post. I.e.: what have you tried?

Comment: Shubham please check the code, I have updated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand is correct you have a modal popup but it displays on the same page, you can write the code in specific div within return statement. Check whether you have added the isOpen and controlling it in the component. Hope this helps!

like below:

```
// rest of the code
return (
  <div>
    <div>
    //your page content 
    </div>
    <div>
      //Modal content 
      <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. But if you are meaning how do we render a modal view in react outside 'root' element, we can do that by creating a null node within component, which will act as a wrapper

```
let node = null
const ModalWrapper = (props) =>{
    useEffect(()=>{
        node && ReactDOM.render(<Modal {...props} />,node)
    })
    useEffect(()=>{
        node = document.createElement('div')
        document.body.appendChild(node)
        ReactDOM.render(<Modal {...props} />,node)
    },[])
    return(
        <script />
    )
}
export default ModalWrapper
```

Here is a link [Create Modal with React Portal and React Hooks from scratch without external library](https://reactcodes.blogspot.com/2020/01/create-modal-with-react-portal-and.html) ,you can check

[image: react-modal-with-portal]